# Does Scanner suppress linefeed characters (i.e. \n)?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I've noticed how Scanner ignores the linefeed characters like \n for new line or \" for in-string double-quotes, it seemed kinda necessary to work, so I'm wondering if there is something that I'm doing wrong, or Scanner does, indeed, ignore linefeed?

Here is the code example, where the commented `String text = "This \n Must \n Work!!"` has linefeed working and would output

> This
> Must
> Work!!

But, if we were to use the `String text = sc.nextLine();` and 
type "This \n Wont \n Work" it wouldn't create a new line but would just output

> This \n Wont \n Work

to test.txt
**Code Example:**

---

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StoringTheString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Type anything: ");
            String text = sc.nextLine();
            // String text = "This \n Must \n Work!!!" ;
            sc.close();
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("test.txt");
            out.println(text);
            out.close();
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
}
```

---

*I'm sorry if I wasn't clear in my post, please comment if there are some misunderstandings and I'll try to elaborate.
Thanks for your time ^...^*

Comment: Are you saying you are typing the `\n` escape in to the `System.in` prompt while the program runs?

Comment: @Radiodef yes, that's what I meant

Comment: Hmm, I've searched thru the SO and haven't found any similar questions thats why I posted this one. Guess its the Linefeed and Escape Characters part that got in the way, anyway thanks for your effort everyone :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a scanner to get the input from the keyboard, then use another scanner to break the input into separate lines.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Type anything: ");
    String text = keyboard.nextLine();

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(text);
    // This is what will break the line apart
    scanner.useDelimiter("\\s?\\\\n\\s?");

    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(scanner.next());
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Type anything: This \n Must \n Work!!!
This
Must
Work!!!
```

Comment: I was wondering the same thing. I couldn't quite figure out the delimiter, then I copied and pasted your code and it behaves how the user is wanting. Good answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String text = "This "+  "\r\n"+ "Must"+ "\r\n"+ "Work!!!" +"\r\n";
```

if doesn't work,change out.println(text); to out.print(text);

Comment: What they are asking is if you prompt the user for text and they type 'this \n must work` how do they get to text to show up on two lines.